# Cannot bind to the new display member in ComboBox

Tags: c#, list, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have a class which give me this error

```
public class Item 
{
    public string Name;
    public int Id

    public Item(string name, int id) 
    {
        Name = name; 
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Here is my function

```
 var lstItems = new List<Item>();
 while(...)
 {
     lstItems.Add(new Item(sAd_Ref, Convert.ToInt32(sAd_ID))); 
 }

 comboBox1.DataSource = lstItems;
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

On second to the last line I am getting exception of

> Cannot bind to the new display member.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should make `Name` and `Id` properties. You can't bind `ComboBox` to fields.

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }
```

It's also stated in [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.dynamics.mobile.framework.controls.combobox.valuemember.aspx):

> `ValueMember Property`: Gets or sets the *property* to use as the actual value for the items in the System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.

Comment: @Selman Genç I know this is a year old - but you said You can't bind ComboBox to fields. - do you have a reference for that because my code works.

Comment: @Ken you should be encapsulating your data. If you have public fields in your classes, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @JasonG , the difference between a public  field and a public property{get; set;} is negligible. you dont know his situation. Can you answer his question.

Comment: In my case, I was using class properties in the "internal" access state, changing them to "public" solved the issue! Thanks

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer is not correct.
The Op needed to change the order of how he was assigning `DisplayMember`, `ValueMember` and `Datasource` and then note the added line of code.

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember="Name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
comboBox1.DataSource = lstItems;
comboBox1.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
```

Comment: the order is not really relevant, you need to use properties.

Comment: This worked for me but some background or doc reference as to why would be useful.

Comment: @RhysJones I wish had documentation for it, I found it online years ago. There seems to be a bug in the Combobox and it only occurs in certain situations. I think it only occurs when the datasource is a list type source object and not a datatable. I know it is weird but it worked for me in this unique situation - I did not bother to delve in depth as to why it behaved that way. You know.... I needed to get my project done.

Comment: I have the same situation and changing the order works fine to me. I am using a List<string> as DataSource. As @Ken mentioned, for a DataTable there is no such issue.

Comment: I was using an IEnumerable from a Dictionary (so a collection of KeyValuePair<> objects) and this totally worked to fix the error.

Comment: @StayOnTarget the OP was using a list not a KVP, I cant remember all the details as this was some time ago . It might be fixed in the latest .net release - I can't verify that though.

Comment: I attempted to bind to a list of tuples. When using `ValueTuple`, it didn't work. When using `Tuple`, it worked. `ValueTuple` defines its items as fields, `Tuple` uses properties. Further on, the order of assignment wasn't relevant in my case.

Comment: @Tm1  Just a follow on .. glad yours works Tuples are different - they are not simple KVP.  I am taking an ed.. guess that the Tuple is the Value in the List where as ValueTuple is not.   It might be the way the binding works and traverses the list object for what to bind to. I do know that this issue only occurs .. (at least for me) .. when a list is the binding source.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I did bind to properties that had the `Browsable` attribute set to `false`.

I.e. the error occurred because of:

```
[Browsable(false)]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

And I did resolve it by simply removing the attribute:

```
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either check datasource null or bind datasource after setting value member and display member

```
        cmbDepartment.DisplayMember = "Dep_Name";
        cmbDepartment.ValueMember = "Dep_ID";
        cmbDepartment.DataSource = model;
```

Answer (score 1):

tldr: Make sure the source you're binding to isn't empty.

I was getting the same error message

> 'Cannot bind to the new display member.Parameter name: newDisplayMember'

From code that looked like

```
bindingSource.DataSource = _MyDict;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
comboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
```

With the binding source already hooked up in the designer.

When you set the `ValueMember` property the combobox will try to find an instance in your list to use reflection on (possibly to check the property actually exists). This fails when the source collection is currently empty.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was binding to a DataSet when I thought I was binding to a DataTable.

Comment: same mistake :(

Answer (score 1):

```
if (lstItems.Count > 0)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = lstItems;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that my dataSource was of Type List < string >
so I just test for that

```
public static void AddDataSource<T>(this ComboBox comboBox, T dataSource, string item)
{
    comboBox.DataSource = dataSource;

    if (!typeof(T).Equals(typeof(List<string>))) // <-- Here
    {
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
    }

    comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    comboBox.Text = $"Select a {item}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have solved this same problem by establishing the order in which I set the properties:

```
With ComboBoxPartNumber
 .DisplayMember = "SuperSKU"
 .ValueMember = "TareRequired"
 .DataSource = _TblNP
 .Enabled = True
 .Refresh()
With
```

Here the `_TblNP` field is a global local field of type `System.Data.DataTable`.