# ComboBox DataSource is not working as I expect

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to get to grips with using `DataSource` with a combo. At the moment I have this:

```
private void EditMaterialsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cbMaterialGroups.DataSource = _docMaterialsDB.MaterialGroup;
        cbMaterialGroups.DisplayMember = "Name";
        //foreach(CutToolsDatabaseMaterialGroup oMaterialGroup in _docMaterialsDB.MaterialGroup)
        //{
        //    cbMaterialGroups.Items.Add(oMaterialGroup.Name);
        //}
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException /*e*/)
    {
        // TODO
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Close));
    }

    if (cbMaterialGroups.Items.Count > 0)
        cbMaterialGroups.SelectedIndex = 0;

    SetControlStates();
}
```

But it does not display the data as I expect:

[image]

If I comment out my binding attempt and then trying the original `foreach` loop I get what I expect:

[image]

I tried setting:

```
cbMaterialGroupsValueMember = "Name";
```

But then it raises an exception.

How do I get it to display the correct value? I am missing something.

## Update

I do have the `name` property in the class:

```
public class CutToolsDatabaseMaterialGroup
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name;

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Material")]
    public List<CutToolsDatabaseMaterial> Materials;

    public CutToolsDatabaseMaterialGroup()
    {
        Name = "";
        Materials = new List<CutToolsDatabaseMaterial>();
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class CutToolsDatabaseMaterial
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Name;

    [XmlArray]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName ="Value")]
    public List<string> Text;

    public CutToolsDatabaseMaterial()
    {
        Name = "";
        Text = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

## Update

I tried the linked answer and used:

```
   public partial class EditMaterialsForm : Form
    {
        private MaterialsDatabase.CutToolsDatabase _docMaterialsDB;
        private BindingSource bindingMaterialGroups = new BindingSource();

        public EditMaterialsForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void EditMaterialsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                bindingMaterialGroups.DataSource = _docMaterialsDB.MaterialGroup;

                cbMaterialGroups.DataSource = bindingMaterialGroups.DataSource;
                cbMaterialGroups.DisplayMember = "Name";
                cbMaterialGroups.ValueMember = "Name";
                //foreach(CutToolsDatabaseMaterialGroup oMaterialGroup in _docMaterialsDB.MaterialGroup)
                //{
                //   cbMaterialGroups.Items.Add(oMaterialGroup.Name);
                //}
            }
            catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException /*e*/)
            {
                // TODO
                this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.Close));
            }

            if (cbMaterialGroups.Items.Count > 0)
                cbMaterialGroups.SelectedIndex = 0;

            SetControlStates();
        }
```

But I still get an exception:

[image]

Comment: I didn't even try bindings in winforms myself, but from accepted answer in duplicate it seems you are missing `BindingSource`.

Comment: Its worth to simply google for error message. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25761826/1997232). You have to use *properties* for bindings, make `Name` a property.

Comment: @Sinatr I saw that. Other comments said that that answer was not right so I did not try. But I have just tried it and it is OK. Thanks. :)

Comment: Wrong comments can't be downvoted you have to always take them with certain criticism. Also often people do *other* mistake which makes answer not working for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `Name` **property** inside your class or your data source.

Comment: Share your _docMaterialsDB.MaterialGroup so i can have look

Comment: I accept this answer. I had it as a public field and not public property.